# MySQL table 30 million records insert into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 30 million record mysql table.

Has about 20 columns of which I will use 15 to insert into another table.

Now I can't use PHP to load this large dataset (selecting 30 million rows and loading into memory isn't feasible), what would be the best method of loading all these records?  MySQL 5.X

I'm using EMS to connect to the database.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the 30M records after retrieving them - are you trying to ultimately page the results to a client? A web view?  Process them in the background?  There are multiple paging techniques but it depends what you're doing with them ...

Answer (score 4):

What about doing an `INSERT INTO MySmallerTable SELECT Col1, col2, col3... FROM MyBiggerTable`

It might be worth breaking it into multiple `INSERT`

Like:

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ID between 1 and 100000;`

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ID between 100001 and 200000;`

etc.

Comment: i can't do a insert with select in php because it will attempt to load all records at once...breaking it up, with limits or betweens will cause issues with the database pointer getting to the 5 millionth record and insert 100k

Comment: You do this from the mysql command line not from a php client. Any other client will probability time out.

Comment: Byron, what if i have to do some minor manipulation, like strip special characters out of a phone number?

Comment: do that in the select part of the query. like `SELECT REPLACE(phone, '-', '')`

Comment: thats a brilliant idea

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
INSERT INTO new_table (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) SELECT `oldcol1`,`oldcol2`,`oldcol3`
 FROM old_table LIMIT 0,100000
```

and repeat it by php loop (with changing limit start value)

Comment: Problem with that is if any of the data changes, 0 to 100,000 might not be the same records in the source table.  You would have to know none of the data will change during the whole process for the Limit to work.

Comment: you can do that with two method. first: you can check new table contents with old table by using subquery. second: you can test it without limit (I think mysql is so fast to do it in 60 minute). elsewhere you can define temporary primary key on  new table and insert old table primary datas in it, then you can insert all. also you can user ORDER BY on SELECT section.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can including one user M_M provided above.  I have not used EMS and not sure what it can and can't do. But I have extensively used Workbench.

A.

- Create the new destination table
- Create view on the source table with the columns of interest
- LInsert into destination from source with simple INSERT INTO SOURCE_TABLE SELECT * FROM DESTINATION_TABLE

B.

- Use mysqldump
- Upload into new table
- Alter table by dropping the columns you don't need